# Does qml supports object oriented programming

Tags: qt, oop, qml, qtquick2

I'm using QML for my project, I want to know if am instantiating a file in another file, is it like instantiating object for a c++ class?

File.qml

```
Rectangle {
  id: idRect1
  .
  .
}
```

File2.qml

```
Rectangle {
  id: idRect2

  File1 {
    id:idFile1
    .
    .
  }
}
```

In File2.qml i have initialized File1, does it means i have created an object of type File1? Please share some knowledge(links) on how all this mechanism works. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why have you tagged this C++?

Comment: Yeah, i can delete that, but i thought tagging an object oriented language gives more responses to this question.

Comment: @Maheshthere is an `oop` tag which could have been used instead.

Comment: yeah you are right @TheIndependentAquarius

Answer (score 2):

In QML when creating a file with first letter uppercase, you're creating a component. Components are implemented using OOP aggregation (not subclassing). That mean if I write

```
// MyButton.qml
import QtQuick 2.0;
Rectangle {
    id: base;
    width: 120;
    height: 40;
    color: "lightgray";

    Text {
        text: "foobar";
        anchors.centerIn: parent;
    }
}
```

... I haven't subclassed Rectangle, I just created a component that contains a Rectangle as root object, and configurates it in a certain way, and adds a Text object in it.

As soon as a component is created, it can be instanciated by simply writing :

```
MyComponent { id: myNewInstance; }
```

Because that's a way it works in QML.

The component name is a kind of class (but not in the C++ or JS way to define it) and it can also be used as a type for a property :

```
property MyComponent theComponent : myNewInstance;
```

Then it can hold the ID of an object created with the given component, acting somewhat like a C/C++ pointer : the property holds a link to the actual object.

But because of the way QML was designed, even if it's more aggregating than subclassing, a property of the type of the root object of a custom component can also hold ID of a derived component, in my case :

```
property Rectangle theComponent : myNewInstance;
```

Will work, but if I try to put an ID of an Image or Text or something else, QML engine will throw incompatible types error.

I hope it helps you.